# Django-autocomplete-light does not show search box for selecting OneToOneField

Tags: django, python-2.7, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to use autocomplete in admin page to auto select a field(OneToOneField) before saving, I am following the tutorial to add a field in admin.

I am not able to see the search box to type in my selections. I tried replicating the select2_one_to_one app from the test project: https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/tree/master/test_project
I am see the same issue for this app as well. Attaching a screeshot of the issue
[Screen shot of the select2_one_to_one app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNwAL.png)

Answer (score 2):

After trying different things for couple of days. In Inspect I figured that the static files were not being loaded same as the demo project in the documentation (http://dal-yourlabs.rhcloud.com/admin/)

I had to update the STATIC_ROOT(Location used while running 'python manage.py collectstatic') folder and run the collectstatic command. The static files for autocomplete_light were copied to STATICFILES_DIRS. After this the autocomplete started working.

Documentation mentions we need to understand handling static files. So this is what they might have been referring to.

Comment: Correct ! The [survival guide](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/30382323418/surviving-djangocontribstaticfiles-or-how-to) i wrote should be linked.